# QuarkXPress XDK

Tags: c++

Recently I've been given the QuarkXPress XDK (the QuarkXPress SDK) to develop Xtension for our   news editorial software (VB 6 based) which basically flows the story matter from the database on to the QuarkXPress document (for example Classifieds). this news editorial software can flow the story on PageMaker 6.0 but our client wants it to be QuarkXPress and not Pagemaker.

is there a tutorial (other than the XDK Documentation) ?.

how to go about because the XDK is C++ Based and its going to take a long time to develop the XTension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quark only supply the XDK to registered developers, who have access to the developer desk email address. The person who supplied you with the XDK should be able to give you access. Quark do also ocassionally run developer camps for new developers. Other than that, the best advice I can give is to start with one of the Sample XTensions and base your XT on that.

You'll need to know your base developer ID, assign by Quark. Whoever supplied you with the XDK should also know the base developer ID you should use, and what XT IDs from the base ID have already been used. Your XT will need it's own unique XT ID generated from the base developer ID.